# How do i pass a sdl2 opengl conext to OpenTk (c#)?

Tags: c#, opentk

I cant manage to find a way to pass the sdl2 opengl context to opentk. Only thing i manage to find on openTks website is a Class GLFWGraphicsContext but nothing else for other window management libraries.

I found another class from openTk called GraphicsContext but it seems it is no longer in the library it throws (the openTk version i use is 4.8.2):

`The type or namespace name 'GraphicsContext' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenTK.Graphics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)CS0234`